# Magento customization - How do I approach this task?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have been delegated a task to add some custom fields to a Magento (1.4 Community)  checkout page. There I should add the following form inputs:

```
<div id="newoption">
<h4>Would you also like to have this option? (it costs you an extra $2.00)</h4>
<input type="checkbox" name="newoption" value="[current order id goes here]"> Yes please.<br/>
Please select the type you want: <select name="newoption_type">[options for type go here]</select><br/>
Please enter your phone <input type="text" name="newoption_phone"/>
</div>
```

Then I need to check if the newoption (the checkbox) is set and if so extract the value which is the order id and store the following info into a table:

table: newoption, columns:

- id: auto_inc
- order_id: the value returned from `$_GET['newoption']` or `$_POST['newoption']`
- option_type: the value returned from select
- phone: the value returned from text input

Now, my question is what should I plan to do?

- add an extension?
- add a widget?
- modify existing extension or widget (where)?

Comment: If you don't know that I would plan to dive deeper in Magento ;) Maybe take a look on how Magento is structured. These might be useful starting points: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Comment: @Lucasmus - Thanks, but I was hoping I'd get more ready-to-consume advice. I know all is required php-wise, mysql-wise, and html/js-wise; what I miss is where should I plunge the code bits.

Comment: what you miss is that you know all magento-wise :) I'm sorry to admit that I'm not experienced enough to give you ready-to-consume advice, but I think it is not as straightforward as you may think, but may be wrong :)

Comment: @Lucasmus - It looks as it is far from being straightforward. I do not get the point of such platforms. Why is making things 10x more difficult and effort-intensive considered so cool that everybody is marvelling Magento?

Comment: @Majid - At an enterprise level it is expected to have dozens of developers working concurrently. I know some large projects I've worked on could not be possible if it weren't for a completely modular approach. It is that modularity which invites complexity, which is a trade-off. Smaller stores might only have one dev and that's fine for them to use smaller solutions or something more general purpose like Drupal+Ubercart. It all comes down to using the most appropriate tool for a job.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - After a bit of looking around I have to say I disagree. Modularity is too lame an excuse for what borders insanity. I found a free extension which also does some modifications to checkout page, it is called Mage_Termsandconditions-0.2.0 and all it does is display terms and a checkbox. Now guess what, there are no less than 127 files in 173 nested directories and 772 KB in size! This might be the case that this particular extension has not been written well, but it is an indication of how *modular* things are in Magento.

Comment: I got the numbers wrong: There are 23 files in 40 nested directories with a total size of 86 KB (no image only text), but still too much complexity.

Comment: 86KB is insane, even at Magento's level. Although 23 files is more sensible when it needs to not only display a checkbox but handle both states when an order is submitted, provide administration to change the terms, allow for file uploads and downloads, modify the database to store a customer's acceptance and display on an order in the backend. ([The extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/133/terms-and-conditions-for-german-shops) is quite feature laden). I'm not defending a developer who invades the "Mage" namespace but I do think there is more there than at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension for this already exists:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1037/checkout-fields-manager/